# SharePoint - What Causes a Blank Screen When a Registered User Views a Page?

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

I have a fairly simple page in WSS3. It's basically a web part page with a custom webpart to display some text and a embedded video from Vimeo, a custom webpart to handle newsletter submissions (a simple form) and a couple of document libraries.

I'm using Forms authentication. My admin user can sign in and browse the rest of the site with no problem, but this one particular page causes the user to be presented with a blank white screen. If I view the source of the page I can see the correct markup and the issue only occurs in IE.

When browsing the site anonymously there is no problem.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: I've managed to narrow this down to document libraries. If I add a document library to the page as a webpart, then I get this error in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a javascript problem to me - the document library view will render extra menus etc. if you are an authenticated user with some contributing rights to the site.  It's probably these that are colliding with something else and causing your issue.

As you'll have no control over the document library viewer web part, I suggest you remove your custom web parts from the page (with the document library viewer on it) and readd them until the page breaks.

I had a similar issue at one point in that we were overriding some functions that were in a SharePoint js library, however as the SharePoint file was registered at the bottom of the master page and ours were in webparts (which loaded first but were subsequently overridden by the OOB file), we had some unexpected behaviour.  I fixed it in the end by adding our custom part to the master page after the OOB file was registered.

Comment: Yep, you nailed it! I was using some JavaScript to modify the look and feel of the document library and this was causing the issue, very frustrating! Thanks for the pointer!